# Handle visuals and on hit logic in an interface method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Just some beginner pleb wondering if this is a weird approach to applying visuals/any other on hit things to an object,

say I had an `IDamageable` interface with an `OnHit()` method and in an enemy object I would have a script that applies both the damage and visual effects to the enemy on hit,
is this a messy or bad approach and is there a better way to handle this type of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is semi acceptable. I would recommend you too do two scripts. One for the visual effects and one for the damage. If you do two scripts then you might be able to use them again in the code but if you combine them together, you would not be able to use them again.